# Where Like MySQL error

Tags: mysql, variables, where-clause, sql-like

I am trying to do a LIKE query in php and mysql but I keep getting an error. Does anyone know the answer?

```
 $addedquery = "WHERE name LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL `enter code here`server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE name LIKE '%%'' at line 1
```

Full code:
http://pastebin.com/PbNyBaaP

Comment: $keyword is empty and hence its throwing the error.

Comment: What is the total query you're trying to execute? The error looks like you're trying to execute only the `WHERE`.

Comment: When it's got something inside it still comes up with the same error i.e. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE name LIKE '%test%'' at line 1

Comment: Show us the whole query that produces the error. It's not that difficult.

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("select * from jobs WHERE jobID>'' $addedquery");

Comment: So your query has: `... WHERE jobID > WHERE ...` Do you see any problem in this?

Comment: How would I go about changing it? I here is the full code http://pastebin.com/PbNyBaaP

Comment: @NaivenDhali You may mean to do `$addedquery = "AND name LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";`

Answer (score 1):

Is this your full query? you have missing the starting :

```
$addedquery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";
```